# Update image on button after clicking the same button in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to code a simple game similar to the "Simon Says" task in Among Us. I haven't gotten to the actual logic of the game yet. I'm having a hard time configuring a command for the buttons I created. The image I loaded on the buttons before pressing is a gray one. What I'm trying to figure out is how to update that image to a blue button that I have an image for after clicking it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

HEIGHT = 720
WIDTH = 1280

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simon")
root.geometry('1280x720')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(height=HEIGHT,width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

def click():
    btn_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='blue1.png')


bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'img.png')
bg_label = tk.Label(root, image = bg_image)
bg_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)


btn_img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'gray.png')

#btn_img.zoom(10,10)
#btn_img = btn_img.subsample(32)

btn1 = tk.Button(root,height=63,width=63, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0,activebackground= '#383B38', image = btn_img, highlightcolor='red')#, command = click)
btn1.place(x=730,y=286)
btn1.configure(image = btn_img2)
btn2 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn2.place(x=818,y=291)
btn3 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn3.place(x=903,y=291)

btn4 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn4.place(x=332,y=368)
btn5 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn5.place(x=820,y=368)
btn6 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn6.place(x=482,y=368)

btn7 = tk.Button(root, height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn7.place(x=332,y=445)
btn8 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn8.place(x=407,y=445)
btn9 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn9.place(x=482,y=445)





"""
btn1.after(1500, lambda: btn1.config(bg = 'red'))
#btn1.flash()
btn1.after(1500, lambda: btn1.config(bg = 'black'))
"""
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I tried to create a function called click() that changes btn_img to my desired image, but that didn't work. Any ideas on how I could approach this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.configure()` instead

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

HEIGHT = 720
WIDTH = 1280

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simon")
root.geometry('1280x720')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(height=HEIGHT,width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

def click():
    btn_img.configure(file='blue1.png')


bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'img.png')
bg_label = tk.Label(root, image = bg_image)
bg_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)


btn_img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'gray.png')

#btn_img.zoom(10,10)
#btn_img = btn_img.subsample(32)

btn1 = tk.Button(root,height=63,width=63, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0,activebackground= '#383B38', image = btn_img, highlightcolor='red')#, command = click)
btn1.place(x=730,y=286)
btn1.configure(image = btn_img2)
btn2 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn2.place(x=818,y=291)
btn3 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn3.place(x=903,y=291)

btn4 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn4.place(x=332,y=368)
btn5 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn5.place(x=820,y=368)
btn6 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn6.place(x=482,y=368)

btn7 = tk.Button(root, height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn7.place(x=332,y=445)
btn8 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn8.place(x=407,y=445)
btn9 = tk.Button(root,height=3,width=7, bg = '#515151', borderwidth=0, activebackground= '#2969A6')
btn9.place(x=482,y=445)


btn1.after(1500, lambda: btn1.config(bg = 'red'))
#btn1.flash()
btn1.after(1500, lambda: btn1.config(bg = 'black'))
"""
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked! How can I make it go back to gray after "flashing" to blue upon clicking? So like, gray --> click --> blue --> timer.sleep(0.1) --> gray